# Use ffmpeg convert mp4 to hls m3u8 and reserver audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, m3u8

I have a mp4 file, input0.mp4. Now I want to convert it to a HLS and only reserver audio with one step. Now I can realease it with two steps as follows. First converting it to a mp3 file, second slicing mp3 file to m3m8.

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 input0.mp3

ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8
```

If I want to use ffmpeg to realease it with one step, how can I do it.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I broke down the command to multiple lines, so you can see how does the syntax looks like if you're using the same input for different outputs.

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 \
  -vn input0.mp3 \
  -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Oh... then use `-vn` option to explicitly disable video stream.

Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, It works. add -vn as "ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -vn -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8". Thanks.